# Simple Javascript code for pagination not working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a simple pagination plugin made with Javascript.
In order to manage the URL I had to do some hacking using some regex and some additional functions.

Here it is:

```
function addPaging(){
        var addPagingVar = "?paging=",
        currentUrl = window.location.href;

        if(currentUrl.indexOf("?") > -1 && currentUrl.indexOf("?paging") < 0){
            addPagingVar = "&paging=";
        }

        return addPagingVar;
    }

    function addPagingReplace(){
        var addPagingReplVar = /\?paging=(.+?)\x/,
            currentUrl = window.location.href;

        if(currentUrl.indexOf("?") > -1 && currentUrl.indexOf("?paging") < 0){
            addPagingReplVar = /\&paging=(.+?)\x/;
        }

        return addPagingReplVar;
    }

    $('.the-pagination').pagination({
        items: $(".pagination-total-items").val(),
        itemsOnPage: $(".pagination-show-items").val(),
        hrefTextPrefix: window.location.href.replace(addPagingReplace(), "") + addPaging(),
        hrefTextSuffix : "x",
        prevText : '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
        nextText : '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'
    });
```

While in Chrome and in all the other browsers this piece of code is working fine, it is not on Firefox, at least from version 38.01.

In Firefox I have this result `http://bestserial.dev/Serie-Tv?paging=2x?paging=3x`

Looks like the regex or the replace function is not working as supposed.

Any idea?

Comment: Getting an error (ERR_ICANN_NAME_COLLISION) when clicking your link...

Comment: @FullyHumanProgrammer sorry that was the localhost. The link is http://bestserial.it/Serie-Tv?paging=2x?paging=3x. You will see the pagination at the bottom of the page